# How to load a file into GNU Prolog on mac?

Tags: gnu-prolog

I have looked at other questions and found no answers on how to do this, but how do you target a .pl file using GNU prolog on mac?

When I boot it up, I try to load in the file using the filepath with this command:

```
['/Users/liam/Desktop/PrologP/ex1.pl'].
```

but it returns this

```
uncaught exception: error(system_error('error trying to execute pl2wam (maybe not found)'),consult/1)
```

i'm 100% sure the file path is correct, so i'm not 100% sure where this is going wrong. Here is a look at what I see. I have a red line to censor my full name

[image]

Comment: It sounds a bit like you haven't installed GNU-Prolog correctly. How did you install it?

Comment: @TA_intern My problem was installing it wrong. deleted it and installed it using homebrew and it works great now. Thanks :)

Comment: I am glad that my 0-effort comment helped you solve your problem! :-)